# Find the density function for the time to failure $T$.

Tags: probability

> A machine has $5$ components and needs at least 3 working components
> to function. Suppose that their lifetimes are independent
> exponential(1). Find the density function for the time to failure $T$.

#### attempt

Let $T$ be the time to failure. We need $f_T(t)$. Lets find $P(T \leq t)$. Let $X_i$ be lifetime of each of five components and each $X_i$ is exp(1). Thus, $f_{X_i} (x) = e^{-x} $ for $x>0$.

Notice that P(one component not working) is $P(X_i > t ) = e^{-t} $

So, here is my confusion. Isnt $T$ a binomial random variable with $n=5$ and $p=e^{-t}$? and so

$$ P(number \; of \; components \; not \; working < 3) = (1-e^{-t})^5 + 5e^{-t}(1-e^{-t})^4 + {5 \choose 2} e^{-2t} (1-e^{-t})^3 $$

Can we consider this to be our distribution and so $f_T(t)$ would just be the derivative of the above expression?

Best regards,

Jimmy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, $T$ cannot be binomial because it is a **time** to failure (of the system).  If you want to **count** the number of components still operating at a given time, that at least is compatible with a discrete distribution with finite support.

If each component's lifetime is independent and identically exponentially distributed with mean $1$, then the time to failure of the system occurs when the **third** component fails (the system can operate with two failures, but not three).  So this should immediately suggest that we consider the **order statistics**.  In other words, let $X_{(1)}, X_{(2)}, X_{(3)}, X_{(4)}, X_{(5)}$ represent the failure times of the five components in ascending order, so in particular $X_{(i)} \le X_{(j)}$ for any $i < j$.  Then $T = X_{(3)}$, the time to the third failure.

So how do we compute $\Pr[T \le t] = \Pr[X_{(3)} \le t]$?  What this means is that at least three failures (but possibly more) have occurred before time $t$.  If only two failures have happened by time $t$, then the event $X_{(3)} \le t$ did not occur.  So we note by the independence of individual failure times $$\Pr[X_{(3)} \le t] = \binom{5}{3} \Pr[X \le t]^3 \Pr[X > t]^2 + \binom{5}{4} \Pr[X \le t]^4 \Pr[X > t] + \binom{5}{5} \Pr[X \le t]^5.$$  Why?  Partition the LHS probability into three cases:

1. Exactly 3 components have failed by time $t$ and 2 have not;
2. Exactly 4 components have failed by time $t$ and 1 has not;
3. All 5 components have failed by time $t$.

Since each component's lifetime is independent, the first case gives us $\Pr[X \le t]^3 \Pr[X > t]$ for a given ordering of components.  But there are $\binom{5}{3}$ ways to choose the three components that fail.  Similarly, we must account for the $\binom{5}{4}$ ways to choose four components that fail.

Then, once you have computed the above, we simply take the derivative to find the density of $T$.  Your computation agrees with mine, except for some minor errors and the confusion between a time-to-event variable and a counting variable, as I pointed out at the start.